# Saving small amount of data is slower than saving big amounts of data in CassandraDB

Tags: c#, cassandra

I have this weird problem - given the below two models:

```
[Table(Name = "pretty_fast_table", Keyspace = "funky_stuff")]
internal class PrettyFastTable
{
    [Column(name: "message_number")]
    [PartitionKey]
    public long MessageNumber { get; set; }

    [Column(name: "time_stamp")]
    [ClusteringKey]
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

    [Column(name: "some_value")]
    public decimal SomeValue { get; set; }

    [Column(name: "is_a_cool_entry")]
    public bool IsACoolEntry { get; set; }
}

[Table(Name = "pretty_slow_table", Keyspace = "funky_stuff")]
internal class PrettySlowTable
{
    [Column(name: "message_number")]
    [PartitionKey]
    public long MessageNumber { get; set; }

    [Column(name: "some_other_value")]
    [ClusteringKey]
    public decimal SomeOtherValue { get; set; }

    [Column(name: "some_other_other_value")]
    public decimal? SomeOtherOtherValue { get; set; }

    [Column(name: "percentage")]
    public decimal Percentage { get; set; }

    [Column(name: "count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    [Column(name: "my_value")]
    public decimal MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Writing 500 000 entries into `PrettyFastTable` takes < 1 minute. Writing 500 000 entries into `PrettySlowTable` often taken > 8 minutes. Code I'm using to write both types of entries is below:

```
public async Task ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable<T> partition, long partitionKey)
{
    var entitiesArr = partition.ToArray();

    var size = calculatedBatchSize;
    var groups = entitiesArr
        .Select((item, idx) => new {item, idx})
        .GroupBy(x => x.idx / BatchSize)
        .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.item));

    await BatchInsertAsync(groups, partitionKey);

    break;
}

private async Task BatchInsertAsync(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> groups, long partitionKey)
{
    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        var batch = new BatchStatement();
        var groupArr = group.ToArray();

        batch.SetBatchType(BatchType.Unlogged);
        batch.SetRoutingValues(partitionKey);

        foreach (var entry in groupArr)
        {
            batch.Add(_table.Insert(entry, false).SetTTL(TTL));
        }

        await _session.ExecuteAsync(batch);
    }
}
```

The only difference is that the `IEnumerable<PrettyFastTable>` partition will usually be much bigger than the other one. I don't get it - why is it so slow?

My Cassandra cluster consists of 3 nodes and as for the configuration stuff, it's basically the default one.

Comment: Can you please provide create table scripts from Cassandra? And anyway the second table record size looks larger than first one, so it makes sense that it will take more time to load it.

Comment: There are no create table scripts. I'm using the CassandraCSharpDriver from DataStax, so for both tables I'm just issuing the `CreateIfNotExists` command. And I disagree - the second table record size is bigger, but the load time difference is just too big.

Comment: Please run desc command on both tables from cqlsh, see a create script, and put it here. Also, please provide info about your servers setup (cpu, ram, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Batches should not be used for bulk loading.

From the ["Using and Misusing Matches" documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html):

> Batches are often mistakenly used in an attempt to optimize performance. Unlogged batches require the coordinator to manage inserts, which can place a heavy load on the coordinator node. If other nodes own partition keys, the coordinator node needs to deal with a network hop, resulting in inefficient delivery. Use unlogged batches when making updates to the same partition key.

See [DataStax C# driver FAQ](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.2/faq/#what-is-the-recommended-number-of-queries-that-a-batch-should-contain) for more information.

There is also a nice article on [Batch loading without the BATCH keyword](https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/08/28/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword/).

Comment: My batches do not contain different partition keys. One batch = one partition key. I guess I should have put it in my original question, but that's how it is :). Anyway - how I use batch statements should not be the issue.

Comment: If you'll look at the code attached you'll see some pointers, like this argument for `ExecuteAsync` called partition. It's named like that for a reason ;).